# Dynamics of the Inflaton field

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

The perturbations of the inflaton field $\phi$ are described by the following equation:
 $$\ddot\phi(x,t)+3H(t) \dot\phi(x,t)+\nabla^{2}\phi(x,t)/a(t)=-m^2\phi$$
    where $a$ is the scale factor of the FLRW metric, $H$ the Hubble constant and $m$ a fixed parameter.

Does there exist a general procedure in order to study this equation and its solutions?